# No me funciona session_start(); en mi login

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, sql

Tengo un pequeño problema y no logro dectarlo, estoy trabajando con un login en php
con xampp y me funciona perfectamente me redirecciona a las pagina que quiero, ya cuando lo voy a subir a 000webhost para probar hay me deja de funcionar no pasa de login
si me muestra las alert de contraseña erronea pero cuando ingreso un usuario correcto no
dice nada el login y ni me redirecciona a las otras paginas.

pero cuando le quito session_start(); en insertar-admin.php hay si me redirecciona pero como no esta iniciada la funcion session_start(); no se queda el usuario y se queda donde mismo

insertar-admin.php

```
<?php
    //LOGIN
    if(isset($_POST["login-admin"])){
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        try{
            include "funciones/funciones.php"; 
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE usuario = ?;");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $usuario);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id_admin, $usuario_admin, $nombre_admin, $password_admin);
            if($stmt->affected_rows){
                $existe = $stmt->fetch();
                if($existe){
                    if(password_verify($password, $password_admin)){
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario_admin;
                        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $nombre_admin;
                        $respuesta = array(
                            'respuesta' => 'exitoso',
                            'usuario' => $nombre_admin
                        );
                    }else{
                        $respuesta = array(
                            'respuesta' => 'password_incorrecto'
                        );
                    }
                }else{
                    $respuesta = array(
                        'respuesta' => 'no_existe'
                    );
                }
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
        }
        die(json_encode($respuesta));
    } ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$cerrar_sesion = $_GET['cerrar_sesion'];
if($cerrar_sesion){
  session_destroy();
};

include 'funciones/funciones.php'; 
include 'template/header2.php';

?>


<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="#"><b>Luxury</b>AutoMTC</a>
  </div>
  <div class="login-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Inicia Sesion aqui</p>

    <form name="login-admin-form" id="login-admin" method="POST" action="insertar-admin.php">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="hidden" name="login-admin" value="1">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Iniciar sesion</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>

  <?php include './template/footer.php'; ?>
```

admin.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#login-admin').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 

        var datos = $(this).serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: datos,
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
               var resultado = data;
               if(resultado.respuesta == 'exitoso'){
                alert('Bienvenid@ '+resultado.usuario+' Login Correcto');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.href = 'admin-area.php';    
                }, 2000);
                }

               else{
                alert('Usuario o Password Incorrecto'); 
               }     
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Agrego esta parte adicional, la pagina a la que se va a redireccionar el login esa ya tiene su session_start(); al inicio y aun asi no funciona, pero es raro que cuando le quito session_start() al insertar-admin.php me funciona el login pero tendria que trabajar sin sesiones para que la pagina donde me va a redireccionar funcione

Comment: `window.location.href` Devuelve la direccion actual del navegador no redirige , para redirigir debes utilizar `window.location = "admin-area.php" `,Saludos.

Comment: Tambien te recomiendo que cambies el `alert()` por algo mas amigable...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pon session_start() al inicio de cada programa php

escribe el primer programa de

**insertar-admin.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
    //LOGIN
    if(isset($_POST["login-admin"])){
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        try{
            include "funciones/funciones.php"; 
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE usuario = ?;");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $usuario);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id_admin, $usuario_admin, $nombre_admin, $password_admin);
            if($stmt->affected_rows){
                $existe = $stmt->fetch();
                if($existe){
                    if(password_verify($password, $password_admin)){
                        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario_admin;
                        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $nombre_admin;
                        $respuesta = array(
                            'respuesta' => 'exitoso',
                            'usuario' => $nombre_admin
                        );
                    }else{
                        $respuesta = array(
                            'respuesta' => 'password_incorrecto'
                        );
                    }
                }else{
                    $respuesta = array(
                        'respuesta' => 'no_existe'
                    );
                }
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
        }
        die(json_encode($respuesta));
    } ?>
```

Comment: Como asi amigo?, la pagina a la que se va a redireccionar el login esa ya tiene su session_start(); al inicio y aun asi no funciona, pero es raro que cuando le quito session_start() al insertar-admin.php me funciona el login pero tendria que trabajar sin sesiones para que la pagina donde me va a redireccionar funcione

Comment: prueba con el codigo que he editado

Comment: Listo solucionado con lo que me dijiste :) Gracias colocar la   session_start(); al inicio de cada programa php y ese era lo que me faltaba en ese codigo

Comment: Si puedes confirmar mi pregunta, te lo agradecería